# How do I resolve error: 'iterator' was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++

I have a header file in which I declare `typedef std::pair<iterator, iterator> it_pair_t;` inside of `extern "C"`. Outside of the `extern "C"`, I include `<iterator>`.

I have tried moving `#include <iterator>` into the `extern "C"`. I have also tried using `typename` instead of `typedef`.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
#include <iterator>
extern "C" {    
    typedef std::pair<iterator, iterator> it_pair_t;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

Comment: You'd need `std::iterator` (but you almost never want an `std::iterator`, which was only intended to be used as a base class when you were defining iterators, and is now deprecated). Most times you deal with iterators, you want their type to be a template parameter.

Comment: This is specifically a C++ question.  Please do not tag C++ questions with 'C'.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `typedef` inside of an `extern "C"` at all?  Perhaps get rid of that and then use a templated `using` statement instead of a `typedef`, eg: `#ifdef __cplusplus 
template<typename iterator> using it_pair_t = std::pair<iterator, iterator>; #endif`

Comment: Which iterator do you need? For example, `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `std::map<std::string, double>::iterator` are very different things.